# Does System.ValueType inherit from System.Object or no?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, language-design

I am confused a bit, maybe I am looking at the wrong places, please enlighten me!
I am looking at [msdn's descpription of `System.ValueType` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx), and it is showing the following in the Inheritance Hierarchy:

```
-- System.Object
   -- System.ValueType
      -- System.Enum
```

However the class definiton does not state that the class inherits from anything

```
public abstract class ValueType
```

We can confirm that by looking at the [reference source of the class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs,915ba3e46633f948) as well.

Still, the class does override `Equals`, `GetHashCode` and `ToString`. I don't see the whole picture here, and that makes me confused I think.

Comment: do you know how to use object browser?

Comment: This was a good idea as well, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't think, this is an answer but Object Browser is the place where you can trace the inheritance. Just remember that everything is coming out of object in the end. It is built-in, no need special annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Everything** inherits from `object`.

Even your classes such as this:

```
public class MyClass
{
}
```

follow this rule, `MyClass` still inherits from `object`. Its no different for .NET types.

Comment: It is implicitly understood, but took me sometime to realize it, indeed!

Comment: Spot on! That's a great way to point it out. Makes sense. Many incoming questions then. I will have to browse more.